# Most Resource-Efficient Way to Deploy Multiple Rails Apps on a Single Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, resources, mongrel-cluster

I have a Virtual Dedicated Server that I use to host small websites that aren't large enough to justify their own dedicated slice.  I am a Rails developer and am currently using an Ubuntu/Nginx/Mongrel Cluster/SQLite stack to deploy these applications.

I feel that the memory being consumed by each Mongrel instance is too high.  I am wondering what the recommended way to serve these applications is to keep resource usage to a minimum.  I have heard that Mongrel is no longer recommended in favor of Passenger.  I have continued using Mongrel, though, because I feel that it is more lightweight.  This may be a complete misperception on my part, though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Having Passenger + Enterprise RoR may help with the memory footprint (and probably performance).